# Wordpress: Footer is extending into content section of the template

Tags: wordpress

Currently building a wordpress site. The footer is extending over the content section of the page template, it's looking as if there's an unclosed `<div>`, but I've looked through the code and it's fine. Here's the website in question:

http://dev2.activeinternetdevelopment.co.uk

Only the footer should be red, however you can see it's "leaking over". Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `clear:both` to `.footer-main` in the CSS resolves the issue for me. The `.twelve.columns` element that your "Featured Items" content is in is floated left, but that float is never cleared. The real solution here would to be add a clearfix to your `.row` elements.

Using this example: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

```
.row:before,
.row:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.row:after {
    clear: both;
}
```